# Segregate data by data types

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data (mixed data types in column A). How can I split each data type into another column?
I mean numbers to be in column, string in column, dates in column and so on
This is my try till now but I didn't get all the results as expected

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, b(), dic As Object, i As Long, k As Long, ii As Long, n As Long
    a = Range("A1:A10").Value
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If Not dic.Exists(VarType(a(i, 1))) Then
            dic.Item(VarType(a(i, 1))) = Empty
            ReDim Preserve b(UBound(a, 1), k)
            k = k + 1
        End If
        n = 0
        Do Until b(i - 1, k - 1) <> Empty
            b(i - 1, k - 1) = a(i, 1)
        Loop
    Next i
    Range("J1").Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)).Value = b
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Istext() and isnumber() with if() or iferror() come to mind working on the sheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to work on the existing code if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things I would do differently in your code

- using meaningful names for the variables
- specifying the worksheet instead of depending on the implied ActiveSheet
- clearing the results area on the worksheet
- early binding of the dictionary object
- dynamic determination of the range to be processed
- etc

but the below code modifies your original code minimally, to obtain the output I think you want, based on your screenshot

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, b(), dic As Object, i As Long, k As Long, ii As Long, n As Long, v
    Dim dataType As String

a = Range("A1:A10").Value
ReDim b(1 To UBound(a))

'first create the dictionary with the datatypes
'since you are maintaining the entries in the same rows,
'   add an empty array as the item
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.Add Key:="number", Item:=b
    dic.Add Key:="date", Item:=b
    dic.Add Key:="string", Item:=b
    dic.Add Key:="logical", Item:=b
    
'Add the values to the correct dictionary item
' at the correct spot in the array
For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    Select Case VarType(a(i, 1))
        Case 2 To 6
            dataType = "number"
        Case 7
            dataType = "date"
        Case 8
            dataType = "string"
        Case 11
            dataType = "logical"
        Case Else
            dataType = ""
    End Select
    
    If dataType <> "" Then
        v = dic(dataType)
        v(i) = a(i, 1)
        dic(dataType) = v
    End If
Next i

'Next create output array
ReDim b(1 To UBound(a), 1 To dic.Count)
k = 0
For Each v In dic.Keys
    k = k + 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(dic(v))
        b(i, k) = dic(v)(i)
    Next i
Next v

Range("J1").Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)).Value = b

End Sub
```

***Edit:***
*If, as you indicate in your comments, you don't want to set up the data types initially, you can also do that at the time of creation of the dictionary object.  Using the same algorithm of storing the item as an array of the same size as the number of rows in the data base:*

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, b(), dic As Object, i As Long, k As Long, ii As Long, n As Long, v
    Dim dataType As Long
a = Range("A1:A10").Value
ReDim b(1 To UBound(a))

Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Add the values to the correct dictionary item
' at the correct spot in the array
For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    dataType = VarType(a(i, 1))
    If a(i, 1) <> "" Then
        If Not dic.Exists(dataType) Then
            ReDim b(UBound(a))
            b(i) = a(i, 1)
            dic.Add Key:=dataType, Item:=b
        Else
            b = dic(dataType)
            b(i) = a(i, 1)
            dic(dataType) = b
        End If
    End If
            
Next i

'Next create output array
ReDim b(1 To UBound(a), 1 To dic.Count)
k = 0
For Each v In dic.Keys
    k = k + 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(dic(v))
        b(i, k) = dic(v)(i)
    Next i
Next v

Range("J1").Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)).Value = b

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. But how can I modify the starting code to populate the data to the suitable column in the array?

Comment: @YasserKhalil by using the code that I posted.  I modified your starting code as little as possible.

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot but the target of my question is how to populate the dynamic data types to different columns without using a select case statement, as this assumes I know the existing data types and this is just a small sample of data.

Comment: @YasserKhalil  You could add an item and the array for each data type as you detect it.  The method I show is easily adapted to that also -- the key is adding the predetermined size empty array as you create each dictionary item, and populating that in the correct location.

Comment: @YasserKhalil See my edit for code that does not involve using Select Case. On your sample, the output is the same except for the column order  (number/string/date/logical)

Comment: Thank you very much for this great help. Best and Kind Regards.